What is the secret leading to that any well-ordered set corresponds to (is isomorphic to) a unique ordinal, in a unique way?
A set S is an ordinal if and only if S is strictly well-ordered with respect to set membership and every element of S is also a subset of S.
From this definition of ordinals, I see that ordinals are "just" special kind of well-ordered sets. But it is very surprised that they has the power to "represent" (i.e. isomorphic to) any well-ordered set.
What is the fundamental point that links ordinals and any arbitrary well-ordered sets ?
Thanks for your answers!

This follows from the comparability of well orders and the axiom of replacement. The axiom of replacement is needed to ensure that you will always have "big enough" ordinals.

Hi, what do you mean by "comparability" of well orders and axiom of replacement ? can you ellaborate more on this ?

Given any two well orders one is isomorphic to an initial segment of the other. This is proved by induction. The axioms scheme of replacement says that for any definable class function the image of a set is also a set. If you are interested in set theory I would recommend Kenneth Kunen's "Foundation of Mathematics".

Yes, but i still don't see how 2 these concepts are comparable... Will i find this answer in the book you suggested ?

Yes, it is also good if you would like to start learning set theory

@InTheSearchForKnowledge I think you're misparsing Giorgio's comment. It's "[the comparability of well orders] and [the axiom of replacement]," not "the comparability of [well orders and the axiom of replacement]." The comparability of well-orders is just the statement "For any two well-orderings $A$, $B$, exactly one of the following holds: there is a unique isomorphism between $A$ and $B$; there is a unique isomorphism between $A$ and some unique proper initial segment of $B$; or there is a unique isomorphism between $B$ and some unique proper initial segment of $A$." (cont'd)

This trichotomy can be thought of as saying "$A=B$, $A<B$, or $A>B$." This theorem doesn't need replacement. Replacement comes in afterwards: the isomorphism classes of well-orderings which are representable by ordinals are obviously closed downwards, and replacement finishes things off by showing that (roughly) no well-ordering is longer than every ordinal.

There are a couple pieces here.
Say that a well-ordering is ordinary if it is isomorphic to some ordinal. Our goal is to show that every well-ordering is ordinary. Obviously if $A$ is ordinary and $B$ is "shorter" than $A$ (= isomorphic to a proper initial segment of $A$) then $B$ is also ordinary: given $f:A\cong \alpha$, restricting $f$ to $B$ yields an isomorphism between $B$ and some ordinal $<\alpha$.
This leaves two facts to show:

Well-orderings are "comparable:" given well-orderings $A$ and $B$, either $A\cong B$ or $A$ is isomorphic to a proper initial segment of $B$ or $B$ is isomorphic to a proper initial segment of $A$ (and in each case the relevant isomorphism and initial segment if applicable is unique).

No well-ordering is longer than every ordinal. That is, if $X$ is a well-ordering then there is some ordinal $\alpha$ which is not isomorphic to a proper initial segment of $X$.


The proof of the first bulletpoint is a straightforward induction. HINT: Given $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ is not isomorphic to an initial segment (proper or otherwise) of $B$, consider the set of $b\in B$ such that $B_{\le b}$ is isomorphic to an initial segment of $A$.
The proof of the second bulletpoint is where replacement gets used. If $X$ were a counterexample, then - using replacement - we could form the set of all ordinals. But that would be an ordinal itself, and this gives a contradiction with regularity.
